# JWT Token vs Session Token for React Native And react Js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

We are in the process of building customer app for an organisation , with technical stack
react js for portal and react-native for the mobile.
During the review, it was suggested to go for session id based user session instead of JWT Token based.

We also want to use OIDC FLow for Authentication and OAUTH2.0 for Authorization of API's
As there are suggestion for both JWT and Session ID which each of them has their own pros and cons.
Security team is insisting on the Session ID's with reasons below

- JWT is Bulky , not revokable
  [JWTs are dangerous](https://redis.com/blog/json-web-tokens-jwt-are-dangerous-for-user-sessions/) [JWT vsSession](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens)
  What should be our choice for security architecture
- Do we need still Session Id to track
- The Token used for the OIDC cannot be sent to UI,as it has privacy and security information
- should we have to go for JWE?
- Can we have hash of the token or correlation id corresponding to the OIDC TOkens  and lookup on each call from client to backend , so that browser or client app need not know OIDC TOkens?
- Do we really need bespoke auth service, Can API Gw itself along with any OIDC will be enough to implement end2end security without any need for writing spring base or any Authentication service

[image: HighLevel Flow]
[![FLow][4]][4]

### [image: Flow]

Answer (score 3):

**CONFIDENTIALITY**

You can satisfy these concerns in a standard way via a couple of techniques, though they require a more complex flow:

- Use opaque tokens that are not readable by internet clients and do not reveal any sensitive information - see [The Phantom Token Pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern) for how this works.
- In the browser use only secure cookies (SameSite=strict, HTTP Only, AES256 encrypted), which can contain opaque tokens. See the [Token Handler Pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-handler-spa-example/) where there is a React SPA you can run and a Node token handler API you can plug in.

Generally these internet credentials behave like session IDs, which are also opaque, but you are using standard OAuth and your APIs still end up authorizing via digitally verifiable JWT access tokens.

**TOKEN HANDLER PATTERN**

For SPAs the idea is to enable a setup like this, where you plug in (and perhaps adapt) open source token handler components, rather than needing to develop them yourself. This pattern should work with any  Authorization Server:

[image: Token Handler Pattern]

Key benefits are as follows - see [these Curity resources](https://curity.io/product/token-service/oauth-for-web/) for further details:

- SPA uses only the strongest `SameSite=strict` cookies, with no tokens in the browser
- SPA can be deployed to many global locations via a Content Delivery Network
- By default, cookies are only used on Ajax requests to APIs, which gives the SPA best control over usability aspects

**API FLOWS**

When calling APIs the flows then work like this, and typically involve a reverse proxy placed in front of APIs, so that API code remains simple:

- Web clients send a secure cookie, and a cookie decryption gets the opaque token. A second plugin then gets a JWT from the opaque token and forwards it to APIs.
- Mobile clients send an opaque token to the same API paths, in which case the cookie decryption plugin does nothing. The second plugin then gets a JWT from the opaque token and forwards it to APIs.

Note that the client can still receive an `expires_in` field if it wants to perform optimizations to check the lifetime of access tokens, but I have always advised against this, and to instead just handle 401s reliably in clients, like this:

```js
private async fetch(method: string, path: string): Promise<any> {

    try {

        // Try the API call
        return await this.fetchImpl(method, path);

    } catch (e) {

        if (!this.isApi401Error(e)) {
            throw ErrorHandler.handleFetchError(e);
        }

        await this.oauthClient.refresh();
        try {

            // Retry the API call
            return await this.fetchImpl(method, path);

        } catch (e) {

            throw ErrorHandler.handleFetchError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. Do we have similar one for Apache Webserver
2nd Question - if we have API Gateway , Does it needs to be front end with Webserver 
So Any Internet facing request received at Webserver and then goes to API Gateway?

Comment: The idea with the Token Handler pattern is that you can host static web content wherever you want, and this could use different deployment to APIs. You could serve web content via Apache - or you could serve it via a third party content delivery network - up to you depending on what you prefer. Of course all API requests involving secure data need to go via your API gateway.

Comment: Gary, Thanks for clarity
 - Webserver httpd - TO host static Content
 - Webserver - mod_auth_oidc - if we use for Token Relying ,this acts a confidential Client to IDP , as storing Client Secret
 - API GW is there to receive Secured Request, which we get via webserver to API GW

 Question is For any API Call, do we have to come via Mod_Auth_OIDC Itself and then hit API Gateway or Directly to APIGW ?

- Token Handler pattern Requires a Backend Component to intercept and translate token received from SPA or browser [ Opaque Cookie] to API GW understandable TOken - Am i correct

Comment: Mod_Auth_OIDC is a respected component - if you use it, it will do all the client secret handling and cookie stuff for you, to avoid you needing to write your own website. It may be the best fit for your needs. The Token Handler pattern is a slightly different approach, where you plug in an API, then the SPA does its own redirects, and can be deployed to a CDN. You would only use one of these options, so choose whatever you feel best meets your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Gary, Same i was wondering, why do we have to implement Mod_auth_oidc and a bespoke token service ,to increase hop
Reason for Bespoke, we would have better control on what kind of correlation id /token phantom to be sent to browser

If my App is just browser SPA then we can have either modauth oidc (or) token service as microservice backend

if My App is Mobile Native - what would be recommendation to go with Bespoke - Am i right, as Mod_Auth_OIDC Cookie wont work in Mobile native [androi] as they are httponly and secure

Comment: Second, if we make tokens returned in OIDC { id token, access token } opaque, if we have to do validation of token expiry at the client side, how it can be done without hitting backend for userexperience purpose

Comment: I updated my original answer with some points on this

Comment: Can you also highlight if my client is Mobile Native APp, is the same applicable too? as Cookies are not working for native

Comment: Any kind of mobile client will just use opaque tokens (mobile apps do not use cookies) and the flow will work fine. See the API flows section above.